# Android: Switching between two activities Error - Unfortunately "App Name" has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm a self learner for android app developer, then this problem came up and I'm not sure if people have this problem before but it says my app has stopped in the emulator.

So these are the codes I have :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        Button imageButton13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
        imageButton13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EXOActivity.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(Intent);           
                    }
        });
    }   
}
```

EXOActivity.java:

```
package com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper;

import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle;

public class EXOActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exo);
    }
}
```

Lastly here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EXOActivity" >
          </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat:

```
09-09 00:40:02.006: D/dalvikvm(1564): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 4% free 3304K/3436K, paused 79ms, total 86ms 
09-09 00:40:02.256: D/dalvikvm(1564): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 3% free 3770K/3876K, paused 35ms, total 37ms 
09-09 00:40:02.326: D/AndroidRuntime(1564): Shutting down VM 
09-09 00:40:02.326: W/dalvikvm(1564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aa7ba8) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): Process: com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper, PID: 1564 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper/com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.mhyuktown.exowallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
09-09 00:40:02.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have a look at the logcat output from the emulator. It will show you a stack backtrace and help pinpoint the problem. If you are viewing the logcat with eclipse or Android studio be sure to turn off the filtering by app package.

Comment: Please use codeblocks (4 spaces) instead of quotes (> symbol).

Comment: one more thing, Intent Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EXOActivity.class); can Intent be the variable?

Comment: can you please post ur both xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EXOActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And

```
Button imageButton13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
```

to

```
ImageButton imageButton13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
```

Comment: You used ImageButton in xml file but in code you used only Button not ImageButton.Replace it.ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EXOActivity.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(Intent);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EXOActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I copy what you typed there and pasted it on my MainActivity.java and it says "intent cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: startActivity(intent) has lowercase intent because you're passing the variable you just initialised.

Comment: @EricDarchis is correct, in the startActivity method you pass the intent variable ie. intent with lowercase i

Answer (score 0):

I coded it & it works fine. Import every thing needed.See the below code. Try pressing Ctrl+Shift+O, Eclipse will automatically add the import statement if missing.

Use `ImageButton` instead `Button`.

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton13);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EXOActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every activity you create must be included in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Find this:

```
</activity>
```

and after that just add this:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"></activity>
```